# VisualSVN - TortoiseSVN - No files were changed or added since the last commit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I am using VisualSVN and Visual Studio 2010 and have recently installed the latest TortoiseSVN (TortoiseSVN 1.7.1, Build 22161 - 64 Bit , 2011/10/21 22:51:59). I tried to commit my changes but get:

```
No files were changed or added since the last commit ...
```

This is not true. Is there anything I can do about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VisualSVN will indicate that you're in a working copy checked out from Subversion by placing green ticks beside unchanged files in the Solution Explorer. If you don't see them, something is wrong.

Be sure that you have version 1.7 or later of *both* VisualSVN and Tortoise. The file format changed between version 1.6 and 1.7; you'll also need to upgrade the working copy on disk by right-clicking on the working folder in Windows Explorer.

If you are working in a working copy --

- Make sure you've actually saved the changes (i.e. Visual Studio doesn't have a "*" next to the filename in the tab, and the icon next to the file in the Solution Explorer is a red box rather than a red tick
- If you've created new files, make sure you choose "Add" (right-click in Visual Studio, choose Subversion | Add) so Subversion knows to control that file

Comment: I see my usual greed circles for things I have not changed and orange circles for things I have changed ... still visualsvn seems to think I have not changed anything.

Comment: Also, remember that you need the latest Visual SVN as well as the latest TortoiseSVN. The on-disk file format changed extensively between version 1.6 and 1.7.

Comment: Yeah I just thought the same and installed Visual SVN 2.5.1. Now all green/orange circles have disappeared??!

Comment: Your working copy needs to be upgraded to the new format. In Windows Explorer, right-click on the root folder and choose Upgrade.

Comment: Thanks ... getting there. I now get: Insufficient NODES rows

Comment: This helped: http://www.scottfindlater.co.uk/blog/visualsvn-upgrade-to-17-format-insufficient-nodes-rows-error-solution

Answer (score 2):

For me a Right-click - 'TortoiseSVN' - 'Clean up...' did the trick

Comment: Did the trick for me. Tortoise also showed that a previous operation got stuck and to run the clean up command.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your working copy wasn't checked out of Subversion.  You can tell by looking for `.svn` folders: if you don't see them, your working copy isn't from Subversion.

Next thing to check is the icons on every file.  Tortoise SVN will show a green check mark next to every file that's committed and versioned properly.  A question mark means that you have to add the file to Subversion by right clicking on it and navigating to "Tortoise SVN->Add".

Comment: You may not see .svn folders if you're working with Tortoise 1.7 or later. Also, the icons in Windows Explorer are notorious for not necessarily being up-to-date!

Comment: It has worked before. All I did was to install TortoiseSVN 1.7.1, Build 22161 - 64 Bit , 2011/10/21 22:51:59

Comment: Ah, it's version 1.6 for me.  I didn't realize that it changed.  Thanks.